# Im() of a functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If   ∀x ∈ {1,2,3,4} , $f$(x) = $ x^2 $ and  ∀x ∈ {2,4,3,6} , $g$(x) = $ x+1 $.
Find $ \;Im(f \;o \;g) \;and  \;Im(f \;o \;g)$

I dont understand the question much. If someone can help me it would be really helpful. 
I know

$ (g\; o\; f ) (x)$ = $g(f(x)) = x^2 + 1$

$ (f\; o\; g )(x) $ = $f(g(x)) = (x+1)^2$ 
What is the meaning of Im () ? 

 Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is the set of the result of the function. For example, $Im(f)$ here is $\{1,4,9,16\}$.

Comment: So $(f o g)(1)$ = 4 and $(fog)(2)$=9 and so on .. and simply we have to write $Im(fog)$ = {2,9,..} and so on?

Comment: I am not sure what $\forall x \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ means. If it is the domain of $f$, I think you need to check if the resulf of $g(x)$ is in the domain of $f$ or not. For example, $g(4)=5$, but $5$ is not in the domain of $f$, so there is no way to define $f(5)=f\circ g(4)$

Comment: Given a function (*or map, etc...*) $f$ with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$, the *image* of the function is denoted as $f(X), \text{Im}(f),\text{Image}(f)$ and similar and is defined as $\{y\in Y~:~\exists x\in X~\text{such that}~f(x)=y\}$, i.e. "*the set of all outputs of $f$.*"  The way the question is phrased, I would assume that $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is intended to be the domain of $f$ and that $\{2,3,4,6\}$ is intended to be the domain of $g$... if that were to be the case then I expect you'll find that $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are not even well defined functions.